# Строка из RegExp

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Существует ли готовый инструмент, создающий текст, подходящий под конкретное регулярное выражение? Т.е. задача, обратная обычному применению RegExp:

например, есть регулярное выражение

```
/Hello\s+World(?:!!!)*/
```

и из него нужно получить текст

```
"Hello World"
```

Comment: Какой текст я должен получить из такого выражения `[\w\d]+`?

Comment: "a0", всё, что точно не определяется, будет случайным минимальным значением

Comment: В принципе есть online генераторы, например [раз](https://www.browserling.com/tools/text-from-regex), [два](https://onlinetexttools.com/generate-text-from-regex)

Comment: @hlearn, `a0` не минимальное значение, минимальным будет либо `a`, либо `0`.

Comment: @Grundy да, поторопился. За ссылки спасибо, нужно такое, только либа на js.

Comment: @hlearn, ничто не мешает посмотреть что используют сайты и взять нужный код.

Comment: @Grundy этим и занимаюсь, спасибо!